# WordPress site redirect all page to homepage on iis

Tags: wordpress, iis

I have a WordPress site on IIS installed on `www.domain.com/wordpress`. I have to do a redirect rule to redirect the whole website to `www.domain.com`, all done well but sometimes and when I visit `www.domain.com/page1` it redirects me to the homepage which annoying me.  Please some one help me and save my day !!!

Comment: Unless I'm reading this incorrectly it sounds like you have it setup to redirect your whole website to the homepage. Why are you surprised when www.domain.com/page1 redirectes there? Also, how is the redirect setup? Can you post the code you used to do the redirect?

Comment: i just do a rule in iis to can access to my site from www.domain.com and not from www.domain.com\wordpress , if i visit www.domain.com\page1 it works fine but sometimes open the homepage and not page1. This is the rule in web.config : <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rule name="ne contenant pas">
                    <match url="^(?!domain).*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain.com/wordpress/{R:0}" />
</rule>
</rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Corrected some spacing and capitalizations; also made some code-formatting changes.

Comment: for spacing and capitalizations , no mistake